# Edit Saved Microsoft Word Document in C#/Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ms-word, vsto

I am not sure if this is possible and every where I have searched, I cannot find a clear answer.  I am saving a Microsoft Word document to a SQL Server 2008 table.  Basically just converting the file to a `Byte[]` and writing that to the table.  This word document is a "template" file.  The file is a form that the user needs to fill out.  What I am wondering, is after reading that file from SQL Server and before opening it up for the user, is there a way to autopopulate some fields in the form for the user?  For example, if I know the address of the user already, can I autopopulate the address field in the template for them?

I know that using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, I can search the document for bookmarks and insert data at the bookmark.  However, as far as I know, you cannot use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to open a `Byte[].`

Is there anyway to complete what I was looking for?

Comment: Save it to a temporary folder first *then* open it using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` - although automating Word from a web server is 'uglee'.

Out of interest - also - what have you actually *tried*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use OpenXML, then you can do it like this,

```
//Load your byte[] array into memory stream and then 
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);
```

You can do what you are trying to achieve using OpenXML without installing word on the server side..More resources on OpenXMl can be found on http://openxmldeveloper.org/. And the open xml sdk can be downloaded from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think the general steps would be to

1) Save the file to the local hard drive of the user with a file name based on the template but with a .doc extension.

2)Open the file with interop, but keep it invisible.

3)Populate the fields with bookmarks.

4)Show it to the user.